# How adjacency matrix shows that the graph have no cycles?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, inverse, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) and $A$ the corresponding [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). Let denote the [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) with $I$. I've read in a [wikipedia article](http://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szomsz%C3%A9ds%C3%A1gi_m%C3%A1trix#Tulajdons.C3.A1gok), that the following statement is true.

**Question.** Is it true, that $I-A$ matrix is [invertible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) if and only if there is no directed [cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) in $G$?

Comment: A stab at the first part: The matrix $I-A$ being non-invertible would mean its determinant vanishes. Since this is the char. poly. evaluated at $1$, $1$ would be an eigenvalue of $A$. My guess would then be that the corresponding eigenvector implies the existence of a directed cycle.

Comment: My gut says it may be easier to prove the statement in the form "$1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only $G$ has a cycle".

Comment: This short [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL7/Sloane/sloane15.pdf) seems to have some relevant information, including some bibliography.

Comment: One direction is easy: If $G$ is acyclic then $I-A$ is invertible.

Namely, permute the vertex indices such that the vertices are listed in topological order. Then $I-A$ is _triangular_ and has ones on the diagonal, thus its determinant is $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not true**. Consider the graph

```
* <===> * <===> *
```

It has adjacency graph $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, so $I-A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ which has determinant $-1$.

Thus $I-A$ is invertabile, but the graph certainly has cycles.

Answer (score 1):

As Henning Makholm says, the result isn't true.

Looking at the Wikipedia article, a "proof" might go something like this:

> $(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+A^3+\ldots$
>
> The entries $a^n_{ij}$ of $A^n$ give the number of walks of length $n$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$.
>
> If we assume that the graph is finite, any sufficiently long walk must revisit a vertex. Since the graph is directed, this means that there must be some cycle. So if $I+A+A^2+A^3+\ldots$ doesn't converge then there must be a cycle.
>
> And if there is some cycle (containing $v_i$, say), there must be arbitrarily long walks (from $v_i$ to itself). So if there is a cycle then $I+A+A^2+A^3+\ldots$ doesn't converge.
>
> But $(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+A^3+\ldots$, so we have the required result.

But the expansion of $(I-A)^{-1}$ only holds in certain cases (I think you need all eigenvalues of $A$ to have modulus $\lt 1$), so the proof isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've also read that, but what can we say when $\rho(A) < 1$? And is there any property that show us in the graph, that $\rho(A) < 1$?

Comment: Apparently if the graph is undirected, the largest eigenvalue must be at least the square root of the maximum degree (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63589/the-first-eigenvalue-of-a-graph-what-does-it-reflect/101864#101864), so if $\rho(A)<1$ then the graph has no edges. (Edit: Didn't mean to post this yet, sorry.)

Comment: I've had a bit of a look around, but I've not yet found anything particularly useful about directed graphs, though my answer suggests that $\rho(A) \lt 1$ if and only if the graph has no directed cycle.