# Is there any graph property that is equivalent to the spectral radius of its adjacency matrix being less than $1$?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, spectral-radius

Let $G$ be a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) and $A$ be the corresponding [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). Let $\rho$ denote the [spectral radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), and let $I$ be the [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).

1. What can we say about $G$ when the spectral radius of $A$ is less than $1$?
2. Is there any graph property that shows us that fact? More generally, which is equivalent to it?

I know that this is spectral graph theory topic, but I'm not an expert in this field. I know that classic result, that $[A^k]_{ij}$ shows the $k$ length walks from $i$ to $j$, and when $\rho(A) < 1$, then exist $(I-A)^{-1}$, and the [Neumann-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) of $A$ converges to it. Furthermore because $A$ is nonnegative $\rho(A)=\lambda_{\max}$ without abolute value, and $(I-A)^{-1}$ is also nonnegative. That's all I know. Is there any result, that say some graph property which is equivalent to $\rho(A)< 1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of an integer matrix is a monic integer polynomial.  The product of the non-zero eigenvalues is thus equal to a non-zero integer, so the only way for $\rho(A) < 1$ is for this to be an empty product, that is if $\rho(A) = 0$ and all eigenvalues are zero.

This is equivalent to the property that $A$ is nilpotent, i.e. $A^n = 0$ for some $n$.  If you think about the "number of walks" interpretation, this is, in turn, equivalent to $A$ having no directed cycles.

Comment: [Equivalent?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1012005/153012)

Comment: @user153012 Why would it be equivalent?  That statement isn't true, at least according to the answers.  I suspect the wikipedia article is mistakenly conflating invertibility of $I-A$ and the convergence of the formal power series.

Comment: Maybe then I've misunderstood the last sentence in your answer.

Comment: @user153012 Oh, yes, $\rho(A)<1$ is equivalent to $A$ having no directed cycles.  But neither is equivalent to $I-A$ being invertible.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I think for nonnegative $A$ matrices $\rho(A) < 1$ is equivalent to $I-A$ being invertible **and** $(I-A)^{-1}$ is nonnegative. Could we use it somehow to see some graphy property?

Comment: @user153012 Isn't "$A$ is acyclic" a very graph-y property?