# What can we say if the spectral radius of a matrix is less than one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, spectral-radius

I am currently studying [directed acyclic graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAGs). Recall the spectral radius $r(B)$ of a matrix $B$ is the largest absolute eigenvalue of $B$. The paper I am reading said the condition that $r(B) < 1$ is strong: although it is automatically satisfied when $B$ is a DAG, it is generally not true otherwise, and furthermore the projection is nontrival.

I am thinking what can we say about $B$ once we know $r(B)<1$. I know if $r(B) < 1$, it implies that the powers of $B$ converge to zero as the exponent increases. In other words, as $n$ approaches infinity, $B^n$ tends to the zero matrix. This property is related to the behavior of walks or paths in the graph. The convergence of $B^n$ to the zero matrix as $n$ approaches infinity implies that the "effect" of applying the adjacency matrix repeatedly diminishes.

But the above is about the matrix $B^n$, not $B$ itself. I am more interested in the matrix B itself, since we observe $B$ directly, not $B^n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1016981/472818

Comment: So, is $B$ a matrix or a DAG?

Comment: B is a matrix..

Comment: "when  is a DAG"